# Error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I have used `Code::Blocks 10.05` with `OpenCV-2.4.0` I have tried to compile a code samples from `C:\opencv\samples\cpp`

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const char * usage =....
```

The compiler of Code::Blocks say me:

`C:\opencv\samples\cpp\calibration.cpp|1|Fattal Error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory|`

Is that means I must to change the include code? with this path where my own include folder is? Thats the path from my `core.hpp` file `C:\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the include directory for each of the modules in to the list of directories Code::Blocks will search for includes. This can be done two ways. If you would like them to be included for all projects

```
Settings -> Compiler & Debugger Settings -> Search Directories.
```

Or only the current project

```
Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories
```

Comment: I know. It was already so in the Settings: C:\opencv\include  and  C:\opencv\include\opencv